# how make Select with SQLAlachemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am using SQAlchemy and python, without flask, well when I do an infinite loop and invoke the select method that sqlalchemy offers, it returns the value of my table, but when changing the value of a specific column from phpmyadmin, in the python script is not reflected the change made, someone could give me some advice or help, please thank you in advance.

PD: I leave the code for you to analyze:

```
from sqlalchemy import Table, Column, Integer, String, MetaData, ForeignKey, create_engine, Float, DateTime, update, Date, Time
from sqlalchemy.sql import select
import time
import os

ahora = Table('ahora', metadata,
              Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
              Column('temperatura', Float()),
              Column('humedad', Float()),
              Column('canal1', Float()),
              Column('canal2', Float()),
              Column('canal3', Float()),
              Column('canal4', Float()),
              Column('hora', Time()),
              )
engine = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://javi:javiersolis12@10.0.0.20/Tuti')
connection = engine.connect()
while True:
    #Seleccionara la unica entrada en la tabla Configuracion
    query = select([configuracion])
    confi_actual = connection.execute(query).fetchone()
    query_aux = select([ahora])
    datos_actuales = connection.execute(query_aux).fetchone()
    print(datos_actuales)
    time.sleep(8)
```

Comment: did you commit in the phpadmin and run python code after that ?

Comment: Yes I did it, and works, but the idea is update the value and the python script return the change of value without restart the script

Comment: close db sessionn and restart it again

Comment: I don't know if the best way to solution the problem, but I taked your advice.
I added in the final line inside the loop connection.close() and the begin added connection = engine.connect()
For the moment works!....thanks

Comment: well one single db session work on db single state and to work on db updated state u need to have updated session

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the components you need to select into the Query in your Session. And then use, for example `all()` to get all the enterance. Please look for the next example:

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base


Base = declarative_base()

...

class Ahora(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'ahora'
    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    temperatura: int = sa.Column(sa.Float)
    ...

...

engine = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://javi:javiersolis12@10.0.0.20/Tuti')
session = Session(engine)
query = session.query(Ahora)
# some actions with query, for example filter(), limit(), etc
ahora = query.all()
```